# Typescript conditional types and classes - strange behavior

Tags: typescript

```
class A {
    x = 1
}

class B {
    x = 1
}

type ThisIsTrue = B extends A ? true : false
```

Guess the above returns true since B is assignable to A as both have { x: number }.

But when the same field is set to private, the types are no longer assignable!

```
class C {
    private x = 1
}

class D {
    private x = 1
}

type ThisIsFalse = D extends C ? true : false
```

Is there a reason why the above returns false?

But when a class extends C, then it is again treated as assignable...

```
class E extends C {
}

type ThisIsAgainTrue = E extends C ? true : false
```

Does this mean just by adding a private field to a class we can actually enable "instance type" checks for classes?!

```
type InstanceOf<D, B> = D extends B ? true : false // provided B has a private field
```

Answer (score -1):

Got the answer from the typescript discourse group. The handbook has a section on "nominal" type compatibility when private members are present.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#private-and-protected-members-in-classes

Comment: The types are still structural and not nominal, simply with a `private` qualifier added into the mix. Consider `class E extends C {}
class G extends C {}
type GisE = G extends E ? true : false`. `GisE = true`. The documentation you linked says as much. You should mention that because people should not think this provides nominal typing.